# How to have relation of two tables for my requirement in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have category  and Product and two individual entity in Hibernate

Category could be,   Mobile phone , laptop .

Product could be,

apple iPhone 7, Samsung  phone which comes under Mobile phone category

dell insprion, mac book pro comes under laptop category

Now , there is a new arrival on phone ( Lenovo vibe k5 ) , I am adding this in product table ( I am passing category as part of payload ) . product needs to be add in the product table whereas category should not add in category table as that category already exists , But if that is the new category then that needs to be saved in the table.

Can anyone suggest what kind of relation both the table has ?

I was trying OneToOne relation, and I am getting error saying that category needs to saved ( I dont want to save category as It already there in the table )

I also tried with no relation , I am facing issue with joining two tables..

wanted to know, How a normal e-commerce app developed ? Where I am missing ?

Comment: You probably are missing several different things, but you didn't post any code, nor any clear problem, so it's hard to help fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

OneToOne relation means that every product has unique category and every category has also unique product. That's probably not what you really want.

IMHO you need to define `@ManyToOne` relationship between Product and Category since one Category can be associated with many Products.

The relationship should be mapped by Product entity (so Product table would contain foreign key to Category).

I would recommend to read some article about Hibernate's mappings or go through some tutorial, e.g.: https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-manytoone-unidirectional-tutorial/

You also don't need to explicitly save new Category if you properly set the cascadings on relationships.